# Copy attachments from list to another list

Tags: powershell, attachments, copy-item

In this script, i want to to copy an item from list to another list.
This item contain an attachments. How i can add the attachments to my code

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://intranet/sales/
$listSales = $web.Lists["Sales Projects"]


$Prospect = Get-SPWeb http://intranet/CAC/
$listProspect = $Prospect.Lists["Clients"]


foreach ($item in $listSales.Items | Where {$_["Status"] -eq "Confirmed" -and $_["isDone"] -eq $null}) { 

    Write-Host $item.Title

      $newItem = $listProspect.Items.Add();


      $newItem["Client's Name"] = $item["Client Name"]
      $newItem["Initiator"] = $item["Initiator"]


      $newItem.Update()


      $item["isDone"]="Done"
      $item.Update()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with following code:

```
foreach ($AttachName in $item.Attachments) 
{
    $spFile = $item.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile($item.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $AttachName);
    $newItem.Attachments.Add($AttachName, $spFile.OpenBinary());
}
```

Put that code after this line: `$newItem["Initiator"] = $item["Initiator"]` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article here:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-copy-attachments-from-one-list-to-another-using-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

I may recommend you to try use [SharePoint Migration tool from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool) for this migrations it's free.